# notimplementederror: can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type python : trying to convert py to .exe using cx_freeze

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, pygame, exe, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert a pygame project to an executable and it works fine on launch but when  I clicked the play button it produces this error and I'm not sure how to fix it would be obliged if anyone could help me

```
import cx_Freeze


executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Consumo V25.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Consumo",
    options ={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame",_init_.py],
                       "include_files":["Blowfish.png", "dojo.png", "Rice_fresh.png", "rottenapple.png", "rottenfish.png", "rottenrice.png", "gameover.png", "Apple .png", "Fish.png","sumo .png","character.png"]}},
    executables = executables
    
    )
```

Here is the button function that is in my source code:

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,c,action=None):#passes the parameters by value  
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()#this gets the postion of the mouse
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()#checks to see where the mouse has been clicked
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, c,(x,y,w,h))#draws a rectangle with on the game display with the parameters given
    if x+w > mouse[0] >x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:#checks to see if the mouse has been clicked anywhere in the button 
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:#if the mouse has been clicked performed an action 
            action()
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansMS",20)
    textSurf , textRect = textObjects(msg ,smallText)
    #sets the message of the button
    textRect.center = ((x+(w/2),(y+(h/2))))#centers the text on screen 
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)#puts the button on screen with the
```

here is where I'm running the function:

```
def menuScreen():
screenOn = True 
while screenOn ==True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#allows user to quit the game
            quit()
        gameDisplay.blit(dojoBackDrop,(0,0))#sets the image to the size of the screen
        button("Play Game",850,340,120,50,blue,gameLoop)#Puts theree button on the screen 
        button("Leaderboard",850,440,120,50,blue)
        button("Quit game",850,540,120,50,blue,quitGame)
        pygame.display.update()#updates the screen so things can appear on it
```

The full error is :

```
 File "C:\Users\Jackj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py", line 50, in getResource
    if resource_exists(pkgname, identifier):
  File "C:\Users\Jackj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1191, in resource_exists
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).has_resource(resource_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jackj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1459, in has_resource
    return self._has(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
  File "C:\Users\Jackj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1509, in _has
    "Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
```

Comment: Could you please add the error message with complete traceback (as text) to your post? I guess the problem is with `pygame.font.SysFont`, but not sure.

Comment: Please also correct your setup script: `"packages":["pygame",_init_.py]` cannot work, because the variable `_init_.py` is not defined in the fragment you have given. Anyway, I believe this second entry to the `packages` list is not necessary, remove it.

Comment: @jpeg I  have added the full traceback and deleted the _init_.py from my original source code.I'm not sure the  sysfont is the issue cause the button uses it and that part loads correctly but I may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find out which resource is causing the exception by replacing the lines 50 to 51 of `C:\Users\Jackj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py` with:

```py
try:
    if resource_exists(pkgname, identifier):
        return resource_stream(pkgname, identifier)
except Exception as e:
    print(pkgname, identifier)
    raise e
```